# Property is coming across as 'undefined' in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that I declare in my controller like this:

```
private addressData: { address_type:'personal', state: 'State'};
```

In my html, I have a select control I'm trying to populate with the default 'address_type'.

```
      <select id="address_type" name="address_type" [(ngModel)]="addressData.address_type">
        <option value="select" ng-disabled="true"> -- Select -- </option>
        <option value="personal">personal</option>
        <option value="business">business</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
      </select>
```

For some reason I'm getting an error saying the 'cannot read property of 'address_type' undefined'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the object

Change

**From**

```
private addressData : { address_type:'personal', state: 'State'};
```

**To**

```
addressData = { address_type:'personal', state: 'State'};
```

**EDIT**

As **`vikas`** mentioned below , Data-bound properties must be typescript public property Angular never binds to a TypeScript private property.

Comment: Mark as answer if this helped

Comment: Data-bound properties must be typescript `public` property Angular never binds to a TypeScript `private` property.

Comment: yes forgot that fact :), edited with your suggestion

Comment: @Vikas it does bind to the private properties, but not in AoT mode. So, it is not *never*

Comment: @smnbbrv ain't `aot`  default if using  Angular CLI 1.5 with Angular 5.0.0

Comment: @smnbbrv what about [this](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#typescript-public-doesnt-matter)

Comment: @Vikas I would argue, but this is a dead discussion.

Comment: @smnbbrv I agree what you said, JIT won't show any issue and AOT will.just wanted to ensure if I'm missing anything.